# Placing Canvas over a Div

Tags: html, html5-canvas

I have an html5 page where I need to develop a small test. There's 2 columns with several buttons and whenever you click on one and drag the mouse, a line follows the mouse movement until it's released, snapping to the next button or getting erased.
I'm using divs for the buttons, since this is to be later delivered to a design crew and they need to be able to change images, texts and placements with css.

My problem is with canvas. I can't place it over the divs, so they don't cover the lines. I've tried svg too, but it has the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A coworker found the answer. Apparently I needed to use position AND z-index on the css for the canvas to be placed on the layer properly. Go figure

Comment: heh, was playing around with a fiddle to test that suggestion before giving it as an answer. Glad you got it sorted.

Comment: I just hope this becomes useful for others. I really hate css sometimes